# Set grid size to windows size

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, window, size

I have the following code to fit the grid exactly to the window.
As you can see in the screenshot, the grid is running out of the window on the bottom and right side. Do you guys have any idea why this is happening? and how to do it properly?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Topmost="true"
        Background="Aqua"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid 
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}" 
        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}">
        <Border Opacity=".9" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Grid exceeds the containing window.]

Comment: Why do you set Width and Height of the grid? Try to omit them if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you bind the actual widths and heights of the window, the `Grid` will exceed the `Window`, as the content area is smaller than the window itself. Remove the bindings. The `Grid` will be sized automatically to occupy the available space if you do not explicitly set a `Width` and `Height`.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Topmost="true"
        Background="Aqua"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Border Opacity=".9" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will omit it then. If i ever wanted to size another element over the whole window, like an image way down below the hierarchy, how could i fit it to the actual content size then?

Comment: @dasd-431 It really depends on how the hierarchy looks like, there is no general answer on that.